# Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Select all" in a terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Headline says it all:

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Select all" in a terminal in Visual Studio Code?

I tried all the usual suspects (Ctrl-A, Ctrl-Shift-A) on Windows but none of them works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On windows vscode doesn't have "select all" shortcut by default. 
Add this:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+a", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.selectAll",
                    "when": "terminalFocus" },
```

to your keybindings.json file.
You can add keybindings by going to File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts then press the "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" button on the upper right of the text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Just right click then click `select all`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that probably right after Ctrl-A :) There is no context menu.

Comment: That seems to work in the "Debug Console" tab, but not in Terminal tab.

Comment: Oh. Go to user settings.
Change 'terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior' copy/paste to default

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added a way to add Ctrl+A on your vscode in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

To select all without changing settings:

1. Click "View" > "Command Palette..." (or Ctrl+Shift+P);
2. In the Command Palette enter `Terminal: Select All`

To copy the selected text right click on it.